# Non-active Jobs - any benefits?

Tags: yakuza-like-a-dragon

Do non-active jobs give any benefits?
e.g. stats earned may carry through
or skills learned carry through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stat boosts you get from leveling up a job carry over to all jobs so its worth leveling up each a bit.Certain skills carry over so you can use them regardless of job but I'm not sure how you can determine which skills have this attribute.

As an aside make sure you switch to the foreman job at some point as it gives you an important ability at level one.